# Flutter: Using Same Animated Widget multiple Times at once

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-test

Since I haven't found any answers to my question else where, I'll try here. I want to display multiple Widgets, which are of the same Type and all have an Animation to it. There are no Errors shown, but there will be only one Widget displayed with it's animation. How can I prefend it from happening?

```
 void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Animated Container on Build';

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            AniContainer(),
            AniContainer()
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AniContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AniContainerState createState() => _AniContainerState();
}

class _AniContainerState extends State<AniContainer> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController= AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),value: 1)..reverse();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizeTransition(
          axis: Axis.vertical,
          sizeFactor: _animationController,
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.grey,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554408/encapsulating-a-widget-in-its-own-class-in-flutter you need a constructor you also add a Key and call super

Comment: what do you mean with calling super?

Comment: Ok I found it. Seemed like I had an logic Error in my Code, but now it works. Ironicly the code above works to. (add padding around the column and you will see)

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry nothing was wrong with your code or a missing Key

here is an example that works fine

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => new MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Animated Container on Build';

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              AniContainer(),
              new Container(width: 10.0,),
              AniContainer()
            ],
          ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() {}),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class AniContainer extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _AniContainerState createState() => _AniContainerState();
}

class _AniContainerState extends State<AniContainer> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  AnimationController _animationController2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController= AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),value: 1)..reverse();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // here are the animationController to can see the animation every tab on FloatingActionButton
    _animationController= AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),value: 1)..reverse();

    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        SizeTransition(
          axis: Axis.vertical,
          sizeFactor: _animationController,
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.grey,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```